# Is there an English translation of "Путь к Земле" ("Way to Earth")?

Tags: translation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektronika_B3-34):

> During 1985-1986 a popular science magazine Tekhnika Molodezhi published a science fiction story Way to Earth accompanied by programs for B3-34 that could be used to simulate a particular segment of Moon-Earth journey from the story.

For example, according to Google translate of [Way to Earth](http://slavav.ru/way_to_earth/) (the translation explains the story and is already fascinating to read), there are subjects such as Lagrange, aerodynamic braking, mascons, and more.

**I wonder whether any translations exist of this story: I would like to discover the space navigation math that was used in these stories.**

I think [this page](http://epizodsspace.no-ip.org/bibl/tm/1985/6/istinn-prav.html) is the first of the complete set, which would make 1985/6 the first magazine and 1986/8 the last.

As a (possible) side issue, "Lunolet" seems to be related, and could be some kind of lander software/game, search for a similar named SF project (a small C/console program). (I can't post more interesting links because *"you need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links"* ...)

(By the way, the graphic art in these TM magazines are gorgeous.)

Comment: I checked and so far, there doesn't appear to be ANY translations that can be found on Google. There's a bunch of programs available from that project though (the Lunolyot thing you mentioned). I tried assorted keywords related to title, various author spellings, and key characters.

Comment: Incidentally, you now have the rep you need to post those interesting links =)

Comment: For example, a C implementation: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lunolet/

Comment: well the Lunolet SF project was one of those links, but unfortunately I don't rememer the other ones for now.

Comment: I wish I could see this question added to the space.stackexchange, but it was forcibly migrated to here (SF &  fantasy).

The information I really want to keep together with this question can be found at "The most popular Soviet calculator" at [SOVIET CALCULATORS HISTORY](http://www.xnumber.com/xnumber/russian_calcs.htm)

As a result, it is very likely this comment will be deleted, but please help me keep this info together... Again, this question belongs primarily on space.stackexchange because it's all about the *science and maths* behind the translation, rather than "SF." or a translation.